# Execute code in a specific date using date stored in a database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-datepicker, android-date

I've stored a date in a database, but if now I want to execute some code when the date stored is equal to the corrent date on the device? The date format is : MM/DD/YYYY , if for example the date stored is 03/14/2015 and I need to execute code in 03/14/2015 at 00.00?

Comment: Basically build an Alarm Clock inline with the various examples you can find thereof, only use your database to keep track of your alarms.

Comment: @ChrisStratton what do you mean for "keep track of your alarms."?

Comment: You will understand that when you start examining practical code as suggested.  In particular, there are circumstances where you will need to re-load your alarm time into the APIs involved, so you have to keep track of them for that.  A simple alarm clock will do it just for that purpose, but you already have them in a database.

Comment: Dude, don't store dates in USA format.  Use ISO.  Display dates according to the device preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Broadcast receiver that will invoke when system date is changed.Use this approach and following code would help

**in android manifst**

```
<receiver android:name=".DateTimeChangeReceiver ">
<intent_filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
</intent_filter>
</receiver>
```

**DateChangeReceiver**

```
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class DateTimeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "Date changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      /*Compare databae date with current system date. you can get system date using calender. and execute your code according to your need. */
}
```

}

I hope this will help you out.